# Ubuntu 22.04 no ctrl+shift+* shortcuts work anymore

Tags: 22.04

After upgrade to 22.04 version the OS intercepts any key combination that starts with ctrl+shift. For example ctrl+shift+f is used for a global search in an IDE I use.

Is it possible to disable any ctrl+shift shortcut interception in Ubuntu? I looked in the keyboard settings, there is no such shortcut defined there.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Tweaks

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

and then I was able to switch the shortcut off
[image]

Answer (score 1):

just to enhance the possibilies: by installing dconf-editor

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

open the editor in the terminal

```
dconf-editor
```

then follow this path on the left sidebar:

```
org -> gnome -> desktop -> input-sources
```

go to
`'xkb-options'`
then i've found right at the bottom, there's an area named `'customer value'`, in this field my default value is `'['grp:ctrl_shift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']'` , remove `'grp:ctrl_shift_toggle'` and only keeps `['grp_led:scroll']`.
log out and re-log in, the prob would be solved. :)

Supi